# Through ajax i want to jump in filter.php page with post data and display result in filter.php

Tags: php, json, ajax

Actually, I am working on making JSON API data.
Through AJAX I want to send data to filter.php with Result on filter.php because I want data in filter.php in **JSON format**.

here is my code.

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        data : "id=" + json_data,
        url : "process.php",


        success : function(msg) {
            $(".results__list__wrap").html(msg);

        }

    });
```

I am receiving data perfectly in **msg** but I don't want the result here.

Comment: Please add your PHP code + clarify what the issue is.

Comment: lack of explanation

Comment: I want to redirect with post data through ajax
I want to send data to filter.php and redirect and need result in filter.php

Comment: " I want to send data to filter.php"...well currently you're sending it to "process.php", so you might want to think about that. Not clear if that's a typo or part of the issue. Anyway, you mention redirecting...you can't redirect using AJAX. The whole point of AJAX is to avoid postbacks, redirects, refreshes etc and **stay on the same page**. If you want to do a redirect, post back your form normally, without AJAX. Either post it to the page you want to end up on, or post it somewhere else which processes the data, and then get the server to set a redirect header pointing to the desired URL

Comment: Another unrelated tip, when you _are_ making ajax requests, don't do this kind of thing: `data : "id=" + json_data`. This fails to URI-encode your data properly and you could end up with issues with special characters such as & or ? if your data contains them. Instead give jQuery a proper object and it will serialise it for you correctly according to the contentType you specify (or the default if you don't): `data :  { "id":  json_data }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an object - youre doing it wrong. If you're expecting json as an answer you should also declare the property "dataType".

```
var d = {id : 1, parameter1: "test", parameter2 : 2123};
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    data : d,
    url : "process.php",
    dataType : "json",

    success : function(msg) {
        $(".results__list__wrap").html(msg);

    }

});
```

Comment: I am receiving result perfectly where i write ajax code in success.
but i don't want a result here.
I want to display result in process.php

Comment: Mhmm maybe you missunderstood the purpose of a post. You are posting data to another file WITHOUT "changing the site". Thats why you recieve an answer.
The normal process is: Call action in page1 and post to handler-file | process data in handler and send back status or data to page1 | depending on the status load another file (page2) to continue process.

So there are three files involved.To pass data along from handler to page2 you can use session or web storage and so on